# Ada generic procedure

Tags: generics, compilation, package, procedure, ada

I'm trying to write an Ada package in the following way:

### p.spec

```
package P is

   generic
      type Input;
      procedure A (x: in Input);

   generic 
      procedure B;

   generic
      procedure C;

end P;
```

### p.body

```
package body P is

   procedure A(x: in Input) is separate;
   procedure B is separate;
   procedure C is separate;

end P;
```

### p.a.body

```
-------------
```

### p.b.body

```
-------------
```

### p.c.body

```
-------------
```

In the program, procedures B,C are calling procedure A.
During compilation, there is an error because when procedures B,C are compiled, procedure A has not yet been compiled. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to provide the body of `B` or at least a minimal version that displays the same error.  Simon may have guessed what you were trying to accomplish, but we really can't tell.  Also, providing the actual error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `B` tries to call `A`, how is it going to know *which* `A`? What is the type `Input` to be?

Usually, you’d solve this by including all of `A`, `B` and `C` in a generic *package*;

```
package P is
   generic
      type Input is private;
   package G is
      procedure A (X : Input);
      procedure B;
      procedure C;
   end G;
end P;
```

If you need the structure you’ve shown, you have to write

```
generic
   type Actual_Input is private;
   with procedure Actual_A (X : Actual_Input);
procedure B;
```

and then instantiate by

```
procedure My_A is new P.A (Input => Integer);
procedure My_B is new P.B (Actual_Input => Integer, Actual_A => My_A);
```

In a different language, [formal subprograms](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-6.html) would be like [formal packages](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-7.html) and you could write something like

```
generic
   type Actual_Input is private;
   with procedure Actual_A (X : Actual_Input) is new A (Input => Actual_Input);
procedure B;
```

to make sure that the `Actual_A` was in fact an instance of A. But that’s not Ada.